# django-newsletter some changes

Tags: python, django

I  use [django-newsletter](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-newsletter) in my project. I need to make it possible to write from the admin panel messages like "Hello, {{ subscription.name }}. Now is {{ date }}". But of course I get no results because of rendering message template with a variable {{ message }} with a string "Hello, {{ subscription.name }}. Now is {{ date }}" inside.

I think I need to redefine some methods or smth like that, but I'm new to django and I don't understand how django-newsletter works.

Really hope to get help here. Thank you!